# Who runs the casinos of Canto Bight?

Tags: star-wars

Canto Bight is a casino city that Finn and Rose visited in *Star Wars: Episode VIII The Last Jedi*. It's basically the Monte Carlo of the Star Wars universe.

[image: Canto Bight Casino]

Who runs the casinos, and receives the House's take? Are they private individuals? Corporations? The Hutts?

Comment: Unnamed "corporations", if memory serves.

Answer (score 1):

Canto Bight is located on Cantonica, a planet in [the Corporate Sector](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Corporate_Sector). *The Last Jedi Visual Dictionary* describes the area as "as a "fiefdom" where corporate entities were given free reign to govern their own territory." For this reason, Canto Bight was likely controlled by one or more corporations.